# Avoid scrolling to off-canvas content

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am doing a small tutorial on responsive design, but I have a problem.

I am going with the classic off-canvas menu swiping in from the left side, but when I enable the menu I can still scroll horizontally to see the full content, rather than using the menu-button to hide the menu.

See the following pen:

http://codepen.io/webconsult/pen/jmCit

Note that codepen hides the  tag. For the meta viewport tag I am using:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

I am suspecting that I should set up the the viewport tag differently?
You can play around with the viewport tag by clicking on the settings-cog in the html frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your css

```
body {
overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

you have

```
.site-wrapper {
width:100%;
}
```

according to your css  on larger screens the main content occupies 100% of width. On smaller screens when you open your off-canvas menu - it produces horizontal-scroll because your `.site-wrapper`+`off canvas` occupy more than 100% of width -`100% for warrper` + `75% aside.navigation`.

By adding `overflow-x:hidden;` on body it will the scroll-bar.

This is not the best solution though - having

```
.site-wrapper {
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

is better but something is up with your header -behaves a little wierd when i add this property.